# Problem connecting to Zyxel DX3101 through LAN

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

On Ubuntu 22.04 (PC is a Lenovo Thinkkpad T480s) I can't connect though LAN to a Zyxel DX3101 router.

The error message is:

```
kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: Detected Hardware Unit Hang:
TDH                  <0>
TDT                  <a>
next_to_use          <a>
next_to_clean        <0>
buffer_info[next_to_clean]:
time_stamp           <1011dbb86>
next_to_watch        <0>
jiffies              <1011dbe29>
next_to_watch.status <0>
MAC Status             <40080083>
PHY Status             <796d>
PHY 1000BASE-T Status  <3c00>
PHY Extended Status    <3000>
PCI Status             <10>
```

and

```
kernel: e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 enp0s31f6: Reset adapter unexpectedly
```

Do I need a newer kernel or is there a setting to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever it was, it was fixed by using the tool `mainline` to install a newer kernel for Ubuntu 22.04. I am now using `5.18.15-051815-generic` and everything works as expected.